# Updating FBSDKGraphRequest GET for iOS

Tags: objective-c, facebook-graph-api, ios11, facebook-ios-sdk-4.0

I am updating the FBSDKGraphRequest and the API Upgrade Tool says I have 2 calls to update. I have updated the SDK to current version (4.31.1) and it says the current Graph API I am using is v.2.11 so I updated that in my app settings on the Facebook Dashboard as well. It says I have to update:

> GET {user-id}4.0 = 
>   Starts enforcing the app's restrictions (such as
>   country or age ) on API calls made without the application's '
>   appsecret_proof'in the request.
>
> GET {user-id}4.0 = 
>   GET /{user-id}/conversations and GET
>   /{page-id}/conversations will return fewer fields by default. Use the
>   'fields' param to explicitly ask for the set of fields you want. If
>   you ask for an explicit set of fields, the response will not contain
>   any extra fields that you did not ask for

This is the part that is confusing. I am only using Facebook for login and to post photos to a user's Facebook wall, with:

```
[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:parameters:];
```

The only parts I access are:

```
me
me/friends
me/photos
me/videos
```

I'm not sure how I update the GET call in Objective-C. Is it just telling me I need to ask for more permissions or do I need to add /v.2.11/ to the Graph Request path? These are the current permissions I have granted:

```
email
public_profile
user_friends
publish_actions
```

I really don't spend a lot of time using Facebook's SDK so I just need a little help in how I am supposed to update the GET calls. To me it looks like maybe I'm supposed to turn on appsecret_proof and start using that. Also, I am using fields:id in one of my requests already.

Comment: Looks like you need to attach the appsecret_proof to the request, which is a 'sha256' hash of accessToken and appSecret https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests/#appsecret_proof

Comment: I was thinking that but after reading Facebook's guide I got the impression that you're not supposed to add that from within an ios app, only from a server. Am I understanding that wrong?

Comment: You ever figure this out?  I'm having the same message now and according to their docs, you only need appSecret when doing calls from a server on behalf of the user.